# css layout layout bug

Tags: html, css, layout

I am currently having trouble adding a border & border-radius onto my layout.  I've tried a bunch of different things, but can't get it to work.  Please help me.  I will provide the HTML & CSS source code below.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="colmask fullpage">
    <div class="col1">
        <!-- Column 1 start -->

        ...content goes here...

        <!-- Column 1 end -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* column container */
.colmask {
  position: relative;   /* This fixes the IE7 overflow hidden bug and stops the layout jumping out of place */
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;          /* width of whole page */
  overflow: hidden;     /* This chops off any overhanging divs */

}
/* 1 column full page settings */
.fullpage {
  background: #fff;
}
.fullpage .col1 {
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

Comment: What happens and what do you expect?  Are bugs browser-specific?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what your after, instead of using
         border: 1px;
try
         box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #000000;
jsfiddle.net/XYwc4/1